# access a azure active directory protected web service using Java

Tags: java, web-services, azure-active-directory

Here is the background:

- App Service A, using Tomcat and Springboot, provides web service end points. e.g.`https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/appA/order/1111`
- webapp A is protected by AAD authentication (express config). An application (web-app) is registered in AAD.  The client id for web-app is *[client-id]*.
- A client secret *[client-secret]* is created in web-app.
- The AAD directory id is *[tenant-id]*.
- Using browser to open the URL above. Showing the AD login page, after entering the credentials, I can get the expected json file.

Now I have another console application which tries to fetch order info from webapp A.  The code like this:

```
String AUTHORITY = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + [tenant-id];
String ORDER_URL = "https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/appA/order/1111"

ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
ClientCredential credentials = new ClientCredential([client-id], [client-secret]);

AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);

Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken("https://graph.microsoft.com", credentials, null);
AuthenticationResult result = future.get();

String token = result.getAccessToken();
System.out.println(token);

HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(ORDER_URL).openConnection();
conn.setDoOutput(true);
conn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json; charset=UTF-8");
conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
conn.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "Bearer " + token);
conn.connect();

int responseCode = conn.getResponseCode();
System.out.println(responseCode);

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
...
```

I'm able the get the token, but the responseCode of 401, and the error message is "You do not have permission to view this directory or page".

So do I need to assign other API permission in order to make it work ?  Or there're some other settings are missed.

Comment: Some of the functionalities require Service Account service principal. So try once with the client id and client secret created using Service Account.

Comment: Try to change `https://graph.microsoft.com` to the `client-id` or `Application ID URI` of the app you want to access.

Comment: Yeah, Joy is correct. You are not calling Graph API. You need to get a token for your API.

Comment: Yes Joy, using `client-id` works now, thanks.  I don't setting up any expose API so I will test the `Application ID URI` later.  Anyway, my problem is solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can reproduce your issue, the `resource` should be the `client-id` or the `Application ID URI` of the app you want to access, not the MS graph `https://graph.microsoft.com`.

[image]